# Javascript: How can event handler applied after 'onload' event handle events that happened before page was completely loaded?

Tags: javascript, onload, eventhandler

This code works.  First, an alert saying 'true' because the image did load, then 'error' because the image doesn't exist. But I don't understand how the event handler knows about the error since the handler wasn't applied(?) to the image until after the body had loaded.

Aren't images loaded before `onload` is fired?  In my mind, the image tries to load, fails, then the handler is applied to the element, and then the handler waits, unaware that the failure already occurred.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        alert("Image loaded: " + document.getElementById("myImg").complete);
        document.getElementById("myImg").addEventListener("error", ErrorHappened());
      }
            
      function ErrorHappened(){
        alert('error');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="myFunction()">
            
    <p>This property returns true if the image is finished loaded, and false if not.</p>
            
    <img id="myImg" src="compmanabc.gif"  alt="Computerman" width="107" height="98">
            
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're actually invoking the function when you're attempting to add it to the event listener. You should pass the function by reference:

```
document.getElementById("myImg").addEventHandler("error", ErrorHappened);
```

Notice no brackets after the function name.